# How to make smooth UITableView in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working with an IOS application. In my project have several UITableView with many rows, and each row has two images. When I scroll fast then It can't load cells smoothly. How can I scroll smoothly ???

N.B: I don't want to load all rows at a time.
Please Help
Edited:
Here is my code :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
float sca=appDelegate.deviceScaleFloat;
float XOffset=0*sca;

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
cell.opaque = YES;

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

UIImage *backImg;


backImg= [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"background-goal-collect%@.png",ipadExtention]];
backImg=[self scaleWithScaleFactor:backImg];

UIImageView *btnBuyImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:backImg];
btnBuyImageView.frame=CGRectMake(XOffset, 0, backImg.size.width, backImg.size.height);
[cell.contentView addSubview: btnBuyImageView];

for (int i=0; i<5 && indexPath.row*5+i<[catFishes count]; i++) {
    int productIndex = (int)indexPath.row*5 + i;
    DBProductAttributes *productAttributes = [allProductAttributes objectAtIndex:productIndex];
    DBProductInfo *productInfo = [catFishes objectAtIndex:productIndex];

    UIImage *frameImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"background-element-%d%@.png",productAttributes.elementid,ipadExtention]];
    frameImage=[self scaleWithScaleFactor:frameImage];UIImageView *frameView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:frameImage];

    frameView.frame = CGRectMake((frameImage.size.width*i)+10*sca+5*i*sca, 5*sca , frameImage.size.width, frameImage.size.height);
    frameView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:frameView];

    MyTapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture=[[MyTapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    tapGesture.tag=productIndex;
    [tapGesture addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)];
    [frameView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    NSString *IconStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"i%db.png", productInfo.productid];
    UIImage *btnImg = [UIImage imageNamed:IconStr];

    if(![self isProductPurchesed:productInfo.productid])
    {
        if([ITIWAppDelegate blackimageforstore]>0)
        {     
            btnImg = [self getBlackAndWhiteVersionOfImage:btnImg];               
        }
    }     
    UIImageView *imageIconView;
    imageIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:btnImg];
    imageIconView.frame = CGRectMake(frameView.frame.origin.x+frameImage.size.width-64*sca, frameView.frame.origin.y/*+frameImage.size.height-64*sca*/ , 64*sca, 64*sca);
    imageIconView.opaque = YES;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageIconView];

    UILabel *name;
    name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frameView.frame.origin.x, frameView.frame.origin.y+62*sca, frameImage.size.width-0*sca, 18.0f*sca)];
    name.text = productInfo.product_name;
    name.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:12.0f*sca];
    name.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    name.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    if(![self isProductPurchesed:productInfo.productid])
        name.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
    else
    name.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:colorCodeDragonBook[productAttributes.elementid-1][0]/255.0f green:colorCodeDragonBook[productAttributes.elementid-1][1]/255.0f blue:colorCodeDragonBook[productAttributes.elementid-1][2]/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    name.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    //name.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    name.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:name];


    NSArray *otherElements = [productAttributes.otherElementid componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    int k=0;

    UIImage *habitatFlag = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"flag-%d.png",productAttributes.elementid]];    UIImageView *habitatFlagView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:habitatFlag];
    habitatFlagView.frame = CGRectMake(frameView.frame.origin.x-1*sca, frameView.frame.origin.y-1*sca , 15*sca, 22*sca);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:habitatFlagView];
    k+=15;
    for (int i=0; i<[otherElements count]; i++) {
        int otherElementid = [[otherElements objectAtIndex:i] intValue];

        if(otherElementid==productAttributes.elementid) continue;

        UIImage *habitatFlag = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"flag-%d.png",otherElementid]];     UIImageView *habitatFlagView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:habitatFlag];
        habitatFlagView.frame = CGRectMake(frameView.frame.origin.x+k*sca-1*sca, frameView.frame.origin.y-1*sca , 15*sca, 22*sca);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:habitatFlagView];
        k+=15;
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

Problem is occurring when the cells are going to off screen, the tableview release all cells of off screen. And when after that I want to scroll the cells are reloading. I think it is not optimal to load cells. But I don't know how to optimize this.

Comment: Check if that cell is visible or not. In case of visible then load the images else leave it. This way you would be able to load image of only visible cell (that user is seeing) and bit faster way.

Comment: can you show your `cellforRowatIndexPath` method

Comment: Have u used dispatch queues for loading images?

Comment: Please share code of what you have already so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

the best you have to do is load the images asynchronously, and not in the main thread.

If you want, you can use my ImageLoader project : https://github.com/celian-m/ImageLoader/blob/master/ImageLoader.swift

All you have to do is using CMImageView instead of UIImageView.
Then you can do [myImageView assignImageFromUrl:YOUR_URL]

This will load your images in the background thread, in FIFO mode, and save it in memory and disk cache ( i.e. : you need to load each image only 1 time ).

Comment: I am using local image and that's why I do not need to download any image from url. Tank you for your response.

Comment: Ok, so the issue is probably that you are resizing the image on display, and that use lot of CPU, I advise you to resize your assets or to resize images in background thread before assigning it to your uiimageview

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `SDWebImageCache` so that it'll cache the images in disk and the loading of images becomes much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //set image here
});
```

What about setting the image async in the tableview callback:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

May I ask whether the images are web images or local images?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using local images.

Comment: Is setting the images asynchronously solve the problem for you? And may I ask how large are the images, i.e. the approx resolution? @NirobHasan

Comment: every image size 164x158 @billyklh